# Continuity on a given set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

1. Given a set A subset of R and B subset of A, can we define a function which is **continuous on B but discontinuous in A-B**(where A-B does not contain any isolated point)
2. Given a set A subset of R and B subset of A, can we define a function which is **differentiable function on B but not in A-B**(where B does not contain any isolated point)
3. Given a set A subset of R and B subset of A, can we define a function which is **differentiable function on B but not differentiable in A but continuous in A-B**(where B does not contain any isolated point)

Comment: By "continuous/differentiable on $B$, but not in $A$", do you mean that the restriction of the function to $B$ shall be continuous/differentiable, or that every point of $B$ shall be a point of continuity/differentiability of the unrestricted function? And in the former case, do you want the function discontinuous/non-differentiable at all points of $A$, or does it suffice if it is discontinuous/non-differentiable at one point of $A$?

Comment: @DanielFischer By "continuous on B, but not in A". I mean it is continuous on every point of B(I think which is same as you guessed after restirction of map). And I want at all points of A this is problem I am facing

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't include isolated points in A because every function continuous on isolated points. and I didn't include isolated points in B because I don't know whether we even define differentiability on isolated points

Comment: @DanielFischer In 1. I atleast know B has to be g(delta set). But given G(delta) set of arbitrary subset A, can we define continuous function on A

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Let's start with $f_A\colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $f_B\colon B\to \mathbb{R}$ be the restriction of $f_A$ to $B$. Do you want $f_B$ continuous/differentiable, or do you want that $f_A$ is continuous/differentiable at all points $x\in B$?

Comment: Oh sorry I did a serious mistake please see question now